# PHP crypt function is giving 2 different outputs on 5.2 & 5.6 version windows server

Tags: php

I shifted my code to new server php version 5.2 to 5.6, problem is my users can't login through their passwords
here's what my code looks like and an example password with two different hashing outcomes on two different servers

```
$password = "online555";
$salt = '$2a$07$usesomadasdsadsadsadasdasdasdsadesillystringfors';
$password = crypt("$password", $salt);
```

On the old server this returned:

```
$2mZiRcZDWVp2
```

On the new server this returns:

```
$2a$07$usesomadasdsadsadsadaeLsXU4E.e7A2gCIvSJPB5xpHBlenxave
```

Comment: the old one is junk, that hash is way to short, just saying. `md5` is 32 characters that's like 15, which of the two is stronger 32 or 15 places, and `md5` is junk so...  that old one is extra special junk.

Comment: From the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php): *As of PHP 5.3.0, PHP contains its own implementation and will use that if the system lacks of support for one or more of the algorithms.*

Comment: how can i solve this issue?? because i have no option to change passwords